# Why is My Network file Transfer Slower Than (What I Thought) it Should Be?

Tags: networking, wifi, file-transfer

I'm trying to copy a 40Gb 7zip archive within my network.

The computer sending has an [**Intel Centrino 130**](https://ark.intel.com/products/59482), that's supposed to be 802.11 b/g/n compatible. The router is a [**Pace 4111n**](https://www.speedguide.net/routers/pace-4111n-wireless-n-adsl2-gateway-2995) which is also supposed to be wireless n; lastly, the receiving computer uses a usb wireless adapter, [**TP-LINK WN722N**](http://www.tp-link.com/us/products/details/cat-5520_TL-WN722N.html), also wireless n.

With all of the devices wireless n capable, why is the file only copying at 2.7Mb / s? Since there's 8 bits to a byte, shouldn't it be copying the file around 18Mb/s? Is my math wrong?

Comment: That looks about right.

Comment: Okay, so my math was wrong. Thanks! I thought maybe I had something configured wrong.

Answer (score 3):

150Mbps would translate to 8.9MB/s. Remember, all the data has to be sent twice, once to the access point and once from the access point. But that would include no address and control overhead, a perfect 150Mbps on both devices, and no packet loss or retransmission. Actual WiFi throughput being around 1/3 of the maximum is typical given interference and range issues.